# Adding nested struct to Firestore

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a nested struct to Firestore and for some reason the contents added are all non-structs, which look something like:

[image]

The structs look something like this:

```
type Status struct {
    Title   string `json:"title,omitempty" firestore:"title,omitempty"`
    Message string `json:"message,omitempty" firestore:"title,omitempty"`
}

type Config struct {
    Name   string `json:"name,omitempty" firestore:"name,omitempty"`
    Status Status `json:"status,omitempty" firestore:"status,omitempty"`
}
```

And the code looks something like this:

```
import (
    "context"

    firebase "firebase.google.com/go/v4"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func main() {

    configuration := Config{
        Name: "Test",
        Status: Status{
            Title:   "hello",
            Message: "hi",
        },
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    config := firebase.Config{
        ProjectID:     "",
        StorageBucket: "",
    }
    opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("firebase_config.json")
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, &config, opt)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Get an auth client from the firebase.App
    client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, _, err = client.Collection("forecast").Add(ctx, configuration)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The above code only works for elements that are not in the nested structure.

Any help on this would be appreciated

**Update 1**

`Status` is not a sub collection but an object, something like:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "status": {
      "title": "hello",
      "message": "hi"
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Akshay could you please clarify what exactly format would you want for your structure? Do you want the `Status` to be a subcollection? Please, provide some details on what exactly you are trying to achieve in structure.

Comment: I have update the question

Comment: Hi @Akshay sorry, but this didn't clarify much what you want. Would you like to get the data and load it in structs? Per your question is not clear if you want to change your Firestore structure or just use it structured after the data is queried.

Comment: I want to add a data using the structure that looks like the JSON object

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Then, you will need to use a subcollection to achieve that, in case you want to have multiple different `Status` within your collection. Could you please take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) and confirm if it makes sense to you this approach?

Comment: No actually, in the Firestore console there is a way to add Map values manually

Comment: Great to hear that you find a method that works for you! Do you mind posting it as an answer for the Community to know that you have fixed your issue?

Comment: That is not a fix. Its an existing one, go to `Firebase console | firestore | create a document | add field of type Map` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Comment: Okay, what I meant about fix is in the sense if it helped you solve your use case. If you prefer, I can post as a Community Wiki answer, just for Community purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore is optimized as a hash entry and retrieval datastore. As a consequence, it's better to create maps out of your structs. Structs are good for Go data modeling but when it's time to submit to the database, convert it to a map.
I usually just use [Fatih's struct to map converter](https://github.com/fatih/structs)

It makes it easy to reason about your data on the Go side and still be able to submit it for storage.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community Wiki answer, based in the discussion of the comments.

The solution for this case seems to be adding values manually in a field of type `Map`. The steps to achieve that are the following: Access the Firebase console -> Firestore -> Create a document -> Add field of type `Map`. Following this order it's possible to create a field of type `Map`, that has the format needed to add data as described in the description of the question.

More information about this type, how it works, sort options, etc., can be found in the official documentation here: [Supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).